# Kill it with blessed halberd: [easter-egg]

Tags: discussion, status-completed

[easter-egg](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/easter-egg)

Really? I think not.

ಠ_ಠ

Comment: It will soon disappear.

Comment: @splattne I don't want to speak for everyone, but I know I am certainly very happy with your increased meta visibility lately :)

Comment: Viva Italia!!!!

Comment: @MDMarra thanks! And Wesley: now that Berlusconi has gone, it's much less embarrassing being Italian. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see this one gone!

If it keeps reappearing and can't be kept up with by retagging, we can talk about blacklisting.